# NSFetchedResultsController what attribute has changed

Tags: nsfetchedresultscontroller, key-value-observing

I'm using the re-ordable `UICollectionView` where cells fetch data from our server when the local model is updated. One of the attributes of the local model is the position index inside the `UICollectionView` component.

I'm using the `NSFetchedResultsController` and following method to track object changes:

```
- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeObject:(id)anObject atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath
```

Is there any way to know if only the positionIndex was changed, in order to ignore the unnecessary remote request? Or should I track these changes manually using the KVO?